# Can you define a setter with the same name as a final field?

Tags: dart, getter-setter

I found out you can do this:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(this.x);
  
  final Object x;
  set x(Object value) => print("custom setter");
}
```

and that it seems to be equivalent to this:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(this.x);
  
  final Object _x;
  Object get x => _x;
  set x(Object value) => print("custom setter");
}
```

Is this the case? And if so, is it intended / encouraged? (If so I think it's fantastic because the first option is less verbose.)

---

PS. Here is my use case for adding a setter to a final field (or that looks as though it belongs to that field).

I have a class of objects which are conceptually mutable but whose actual implementation is immutable, because they are just snapshots from a database and what should be modified is the database itself not the local model, so the "fake" setters modify the data in the database (which in turn causes a new snapshot to be pushed to the client, creating the illusion that the object is indeed mutable).

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the first version is allowed?  I get an error: "The name 'x' is already defined." 2. Even if it were allowed, I would not recommend it simply because it's very misleading that it exposes a setter for `x` but can't actually change it.

Comment: @jamesdlin My bad, I was missing a `final` keyword

Comment: Then why have a setter for `x` at all?  It's very misleading.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have a class of objects which are conceptually mutable but the actual implementation is immutable, because they are just snapshots from a database and what should be modified is the database itself not the local model, so the "fake" setters modify the data in the database (which in turn causes a new snapshot to be pushed to the client, creating the illusion that the object is indeed mutable).